# Помогите отправить запрос на сервер RabbiMQ (с помощью Swift и библиотеки RMQClient)

Tags: swift, клиент-сервер, rabbitmq

Необходимо отправить сообщение на сервер и получить ответ.
Использую библиотеку [RMQClient](https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html).
Проблема в том что не могу понять где установить свойства для сообщения.
Вот как я отправляю:

```
let json: JSON =  [ "clientNum": "1234" ]
let msg = json.rawString()
let msg2 = msg!.data(using: .utf8)!

//соединение
let conn = RMQConnection(uri: "amqp://test:test@106.000.000.000:5672",
                                 delegate: RMQConnectionDelegateLogger())
conn.start()
let ch = conn.createChannel()
let q = ch.queue("1234")
ch.queueBind("client_" + q.name, exchange: "sysYou", routingKey: "1234")
ch.defaultExchange().publish(msg2, routingKey: "1234")
//Либо вот так могу отправить: q.publish(msg!.data(using: .utf8)!)
//Как лучше?
```

Но не пойму где добавить к свойствам сообщения "message_id" и "type" это должно быть в запросе а именно в свойствах сообщения.
Т.е. что-то типа вида:

```
properties = {'message_id': '1212121',
                  'type': "текст" }
```

Подскажите как их установить?

Нашел как на Яве это делается:

```
AMQP.BasicProperties properties = new AMQP.BasicProperties();
        properties  = properties.builder().expiration(""+message.getExpiration()).type(message.getType().name()).messageId(message.getId()).build();
```

Но в библиотеке swift такого и класса и функции не нашел

Может кто знает?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не хотел устанавливать RabbiMQ локально и создал новый сервер на cloudamqp.com, это бесплатно (для разработки).

Podfile:

```
pod 'RMQClient'
```

Работающий код:

```
import UIKit
import RMQClient

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let uri = "amqp://..."

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.send()
        self.receive()
    }

    func send() {
        print("Attempting to connect to local RabbitMQ broker")
        let conn = RMQConnection(uri: uri, delegate: RMQConnectionDelegateLogger())
        conn.start()
        let ch = conn.createChannel()
        var props: [RMQValue] = []
        props.append(RMQBasicAppId("my app ID"))
        props.append(RMQBasicContentType("some/contenttype"))
        props.append(RMQBasicCorrelationId("my correlation ID"))
        props.append(RMQBasicHeaders(["some": RMQLongstr("header")]))
        props.append(RMQBasicMessageId("1212121"))
        props.append(RMQBasicType("мой текст"))
        props.append(RMQBasicPriority(9))
        props.append(RMQBasicReplyTo("my.sender"))
        props.append(RMQBasicTimestamp(Date()))
        let options = RMQBasicPublishOptions()
        let data = "Hello World!".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        ch.defaultExchange().publish(data, routingKey: "hello", properties: props as! [RMQValue & RMQBasicValue], options: options)
    }

    func receive() {
        print("Attempting to connect to local RabbitMQ broker")
        let conn = RMQConnection(uri: uri, delegate: RMQConnectionDelegateLogger())
        conn.start()
        let ch = conn.createChannel()
        let q = ch.queue("hello")
        print("Waiting for messages.")
        q.subscribe({(_ message: RMQMessage) -> Void in
            print("Received \(String(data: message.body, encoding: .utf8))")
            print("message ID: \(message.messageID())")
        })
    }
}
```

В переменной uri должен быть url вашего сервера.

Результат:

```
Waiting for messages.
Received Optional("Hello World!")
message ID: Optional("1212121")
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Именно то, что искал.

Comment: Подскажите, а как дождаться получения данных либо узнать что вышел тайм аут (данные отдаются с задержкой и всегда разной, как ее обработать)?

Comment: @ПетровКирилл Можете уточнить вопрос? Насколько я понимаю концепцию, RabbiMQ получит сообщение в любом случае, если оно придет. Если упадет сеть - то после ее восстановления. У самого сообщения timeout нет, timeout есть только у самого соединения, которое должно быть пересоздано после его наступления.

Comment: var answer = [String:String]() q.subscribe({(_ message: RMQMessage) -> Void in
            let messageText = String(data: message.body, encoding: .utf8)
            print("Received \(String(data: message.body, encoding: .utf8))")
            let json = try? JSON(data: message.body)
            answer["type"] = message.messageType()
            for (key, value) in (json?.dictionary)! {
                answer[key] = value.string
            }
        }) return answer  тут я всегда получаю пустоту, вот и вопрос как дождаться получения данных?

Comment: Если перед return добавить sleep(4) то все более менее ок!

Comment: @ПетровКирилл Вы не должны использовать return внутри замыканий. Используйте callback-и. Вот пример https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/functional-swift-all-about-closures-310bc8af31dd

Comment: Приведенный код внутри функци и у функции ретурн.